# Python four-digit password finder

Tags: python, for-loop, passwords

I am trying to create a program where you enter with a numeric password of 4 or 3 digits, and a for loop always increases "i" by one up to the number of the password, all this works, but if I write for example 0001 the for loop goes to infinity because it starts from 0 and not from 0000, while if I write 1234 the password is 1234 how can I do to make sure that: 0000, 0001, 0011, 0111 do not make the for loop go to infinity but are 0000 or 0001 etc

```
# import only system from os
from os import system, name
  
# define our clear function
def clear():
  
    # for windows
    if name == 'nt':
        _ = system('cls')
  
    # for mac and linux(here, os.name is 'posix')
    else:
        _ = system('clear')

strpw = input()

#check if the number is 4-digit or 3-digit
if len(strpw) <= 4 and len(strpw) >= 3:
    i = 0
    #add 1 to i until i equals strpw
    while i != strpw:
        print(i)
        clear()
        i = i + 1
        if str(i) == strpw:
            print("the password is: " + str(i))
            break
else:
    print("the password is too short or too long")
```

Comment: why do You have this: `_ = system('cls')` You can easily just leave this: `system('cls')`

Comment: @Matiiss i don't know exactly in the tutorial it said to do this (i am new today is the first day i use python)

Comment: interesting, anyhow that is pretty pointless since `system()` returns `None` so the variable wouldn't have any use really anyways, however this is a "throwaway variable" meaning that it is not accessible - it gets deleted - so double no use, either how this use in this manner is pretty pointless so might as well just use only `system('cls')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maintain your password as an integer. When you need to display it, only then convert it the the required string format. This will simplify everything. A minimal example:

```
strpw = "0003"

pass_length = len(strpw)
pw = int(strpw)

i = 0

while i != pw: # keep as int for comparint and incrementing
    # convert to string for printing
    print(str(i).zfill(pass_length))
    i += 1
```

Prints:

> 0000
> 0001
> 0002

Answer (score 0):

From this line in code `strpw = int(input())` you are taking `string` input and converting it to `int`. This is causing the problems.
e.g.

Taking input `0111` if we convert it to `int` it becomes `111`. While if we keep it as `string` it remains `0111`.

so you only have to keep your password in string format.

Comment: I removed the password variable and transformed strpw directly into a string by removing int (), but the problem remains. I wrote the script in the question, modifying the question

Comment: so You basically solved nothing? is this what it is, like how do You imagine increasing the string?